# Any good timeline library for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, timeline

I want to implement an iPhone App representing different events occurred in different dates. So I like the idea of scrollable timeline.

**Does anyone know of an existing library to use for implementing a scrollable timeline?**

Answer (score 0):

why not use UITableView.. when you reach at bottom via scrolling.. add more rows in tableview dynamically.

Comment: why a downvote?? please don't downvote without a comment... I am not getting why you guys can't build the simple timeline with UITableView?? Trust me .. its quite simple to build one..